# Handling truncated POST data in php

Tags: php, forms, apache, file-upload

I have a form with a small number (up to 10) of inputs. One of those inputs is a file upload input. The form layout is as follows:

```
<form method="post" ...>
<input type="hidden" name="input_no_1" value="value_no_1">
<input type="file" name="input_no_2">
<input type="hidden" name="input_no_3" value="value_no_3">
<button type="submit">send</button>
```

99.9% of the time this form works fine and I get all the data on the PHP side. However, every once in a while, the POST data gets truncated, and the $_POST variable contains only this:

```
input_no_1 => value_no_1
```

The file input and every other input that follows the file input are missing.

This error happens almost exclusively with user agents that contain "Mobile Safari". I suspect that mobile phone users could be using a less reliable network connection and as a result, their request gets aborted and PHP doesn't receive the entire uploaded data.

In my application, I need to know whether the data in the $_POST array is complete or not. I was expecting that if the HTTP server doesn't receive the entire request, I wouldn't even see it from the PHP side.

I am using apache/fpm. The `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` are both set to 2G and are nowhere near the size of the uploaded files.

The question: what is the best way to handle incomplete POST data in PHP? Is there a way to prevent these requests from reaching my application, and if not, is there a way to know whether the posted data is complete? I prefer not to add any fields at the end of the form just to find out whether the request is complete or not :)

Comment: If it behaves like you say (everything after the file input is missing), including a "control" input at the end actually seems like a elegant solution to detect a incomplete payload. Thing is, you'll probably always have to send something to the server in order to check what you sent (from the client) and what you got (in the server). Maybe calculate a hash of the data and compare it to what you receive but, still, you have to actually send it.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this is a case of needing some server side form validation. Assuming the above fields are all required, something like the following might work for you:

```
if (!isset($_POST['input_no_1'], $_POST['input_no_2'], $_FILES['input_no_2'])) {
    die('Form not filled completely');
} else {
    //process form
}
```

Comment: The question was about why I'm getting an incomplete payload on the PHP side and how to check whether the payload is complete as a whole.  I can't check each field individually, as form inputs are generated dynamically by javascript and the server-side script does not know upfront what fields must be present.